# MySQL Select with LIKE and WHERE

Tags: mysql, select, null, where-clause, sql-like

I have a table of biographical data, and I need to do a query that selects people who have the word "died" in their bio and whose death date is NULL. This doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE bio LIKE '%died%'
AND death_date IS NULL
```

That selects everyone whose death_date is null, but also selects people who don't have the word "died" in their bio. Can I do this in one query?

Comment: Are you sure that it returns people who don't have 'died' in their bio?  Remember it will also include words containing died such as studied, and imbodied.

Comment: share sample data which is behaving like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a word like 'completelydied' and they are still going to be selected. Check carefully if 'died' phrase does not exists as part of some word in the records that you got selected.

Comment: Do not forget that adding space in front of 'died' will not work if the word is in the beginning of the bio.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the problem is the quotes, use " instead of ' to wrap the LIKE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE bio LIKE "%died%"
AND death_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Running the query like this returns the same results.

Comment: What data type is the "bio" field?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you make bio upper case and have like "%DIED%" also make sure that death_date is really null, see if you get an answer from both where cases independently. What response are you getting?

Comment: Using WHERE death_date IS NULL by itself returns the people whose death_date is NULL.

Comment: what about? WHERE UPPER(bio) LIKE '%DIED%'